# ICU version compatibility Symfony 3.1

Tags: nginx, symfony, ubuntu-16.04, symfony-3.1

I have a problem installing symfony 3.1 in php7, nginx and ubuntu 16.04, i have this error:

intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (55.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1) 
To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

How can i solve this issue? can i change symfony and use IC 55.1 instead of ICU 57.1?

Comment: `sudo apt install php7.0-intl`

Comment: i already install this extension thanks

Comment: can I do that with PHP 5.6.25 (cli)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I presume you get this when you run:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

This is just a warning and you can safely ignore the message. I've response to similar questions on this. See this URL for more details:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007

Comment: i was running the config.php  , i run the  php bin/symfony_requirements, and you are right is an optional recommendation.  thank you .

Comment: I know that it's optional, but if one wanted to upgrade PHP Intl ICU to 57.1, do you know how that is done?

Comment: No idea on how to install ICU 57.1 properly. I've tried a number of things and no luck. Probably best to ignore the warning message.

Answer (score 6):

To install ICU 57.1 run:

```
curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/57.1/icu4c-57_1-src.tgz && tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp && cd /tmp/icu/source && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
```

Answer (score 2):

run

```
curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/57.1/icu4c-57_1-src.tgz && tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp && cd /tmp/icu/source && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install
```

than run

```
sudo pecl install intl
```