# MAMP upgrade PHP ICU version in Symfony checker

Tags: php, symfony

I've just downloaded Symfony and I'm having a issue during the checking before starting a project.

After activating a php accelerator and disabling some extensions in php.ini, the system is displaying this message: intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (56.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)

I've been searching through the documentation and I was not able to find how to fix that issue. 
Do I miss anything during the installation? How I upgrade this icu system?

Information about system:
OSX with MAMP
Running php 7
Symfony 3.1.14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you get this when you run:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

This is just a warning and you can safely ignore the message. I've responded to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1/39378273#39378273) on this. See this URL for more details:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007

Comment: Hi There!
I get this message when I run the config.php on my new created Symfony project.
I don't see a "skip" button in that message and I'm not able to configure the database access.

Comment: Are you trying to run `web/config.php` directly via command line? If so, that's incorrect. That file is run indirectly, you shouldn't be running it. What point of settings up you Symfony project are you at right now?