# Having trouble to pass through symfony configuration checker

Tags: php, symfony, dll

I am new to symfony and i downloaded it using composer due to some issue. When i tried to check configuration using `http://localhost:8000/config.php`
showing the following error
[image]

When i tried to start server using `php app/console server:run` after replacing `php_intl.dll` in my `php/ext/` directory downloaded from [`http://pecl.php.net/package/intl`](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl), it gives me following error
[image]

Now, when i start server after adding `php_icuuc51.dll` in php directory, gives me another missing dll file error

[image]

But after adding `icudt51.dll` from http://fixfile.info/icudt51.dll/en-download-40530.html and starting server, i got another error
[image]

which i am having difficulty to fix it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi there Kumari. Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intl ICU message is just a warning, you can safely ignore it.
See this post for a similar question and response from me:

[MAMP upgrade PHP ICU version in Symfony checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645030/mamp-upgrade-php-icu-version-in-symfony-checker/39645322#39645322)