# Symfony 3 or 4 on Ubuntu 16.04 or Debian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, icu, debian-jessie

I'm attempting to use Symfony. I've tried on both Debian 8 (jessie) and Ubuntu 16.04 servers. On both, I am told by the Symfony config that the version of ICU is too low (52 or 55). It needs to be at 59.1. I have tried everything I could find- including installed 59.1 from a tar ball instructed on another question here. Nothing I found ever changed the version. What do I need to do here to get this running?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? From my understanding, you should be looking to enable the php-intl extension in your php.ini, http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php which should be packaged in your php installation with either linux distro.

Comment: I tried php7.1 for Symfony 4 
and 7.1 and 5.6 for Symfony 3.

It was enabled but I could not upgrade the version.

Comment: Yea, as long as you have the `php-intl` extension enabled in your php.ini, you should be all set. You can validate this in Symfony's own travis build for 
 Symfony 3.3 and PHP 7.1 https://travis-ci.org/symfony/symfony/jobs/275058815#L1260

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ICU version compatibility Symfony 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning only. You don't need to do anything. I've [answered this question on SO multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1). See the screenshot below, which you get when you run `php bin/symfony_requirements`:

[image]

As long as running the `bin/symfony_requirements` shows the green OK, then you are set, otherwise it will tell what you still need.

Comment: So, this question (and many others you've answered) should be marked as duplicate and not answered.

Comment: Ah. Got it. I was under the impression that it would not function properly without this upgrade. And though previously asked/answered Don, I was still unable to upgrade my version of ICU.