# intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated

Tags: symfony, xampp, icu, symfony-3.3

Hello symfony developers, when i try the configuration checker (http://localhost/test/web/config.php) i got this erreur:

**To enhance your Symfony experience, it’s recommended that you fix the following:**

**1-intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (57.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (59.1)
To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.**

i'm using symfony 3.3.9 with XAMPP as server and Windows 7 as OS.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ICU version compatibility Symfony 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1)

Comment: I've already [answered this previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1/39378273#39378273).